# How can I add a d3d effect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccQfjY63Oaw
I want to add this type of effect in my image and video like this youtube video. But how can I do this? Is there any framework which can help me to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that easy actually. But this tutorial should get you started: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5999357-video-depth-maps-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started What you do is get the depth map of a photo, then, extract the white part and mask it to the actual photo. Then you can superimpose it on top actual photo and move it side to side to achieve a 3D look.

This of course assuming you take the photo with iPhones that have 2 or more cameras for depth capturing. It won't work with old phones or ipads.